# How would burn-proof people react to enflamed alcohol?

Tags: biology, humans, fire

The Ardeites are a group of humans who are wholly immune to being injured by heat and flame. Furthermore, they cannot feel pain. All other features (including instinctive reactions to extreme temperatures and fire) are exactly the same as in regular humans.

Often they indulge in hard liquors, which sometimes they fill up their stomachs with. My question is, what would happen to them if the alcohol in their stomach was ignited, specifically regarding natural reflexes?

Comment: From where does "the alcohol in stomach" get the oxygen?

Comment: ...I imagine they'd make a vigorous attempt to defend themselves from whoever's trying to cram an air hose and igniter down their esophagus, much like a normal human would.

Comment: Ignoring the simple truth that they wouldn't care a thing about it because it's as meaningless to them as filling our lungs with air is to us, I can easily imagine their adolescents and young adults filling their time with their version(s) of [blue dart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fart_lighting) tournaments. I think the funniest would be some drunk barfing out behind the bar while a another sneaks up behind and throws a match - but there could/would be others. Not that hard alcohol is all that explosive (it's not gasoline, after all).

Comment: A given answer goes into the psychology behind it, but I interpret your question to be a prompt for a more biologically (as your tag implies) or physically based answer. Given this is currently in the close queue, can you specify more precisely what you hope for in an answer?

Comment: The real question would be, "would they survive childhood enough to get to where they could fill their stomachs with alcohol?"  A young child learns a lot from experiencing pain. Lack of pain response would lead to many fatal situations during childhood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Flaming Shots**

I've done it, and I'm not immune to Fire.
Other people have also done it, who are also not immune to fire.

If I was immune to fire - you can bet that there would be alot more shenanigans involving the always 'fun' combination of Fire + Alcohol.

If they don't feel pain and are immune to the effects of Fire - then they would be going Ham on all the fun things you can do with Fire:

Fire Breathing? Yep.
Flaming Beverages? Yep.
Fire Walking? Yep.
Trying to Burp fireballs at each other whilst yelling 'HADOUKEN!'? Yep.
Flaming projectile Vomiting? Yep.

TL;DR - Humans (who aren't immune to fire) do dumb things when Alcohol and Fire are combined. The Ardeites will do even dumber things with Alcohol and Fire because they can't get hurt.

Answer (score 6):

## Humans don't have an instinctive aversion to fire

As any parent will tell you, if you leave a child around a fire or a stove, they'll probably try to touch it. Humans are deeply curious about fires, not averted by it, except from experience.

We learn that fire is dangerous by being damaged. If they're not damaged by it, setting their insides on fire would just be a fascinating and weird experience.

Answer (score 0):

### Not the stomach but the lungs

Handwaving the "how to ignite alcohol inside somebody" igniting it in the stomach won't do much since the lack of oxygen would end the fire probably before the person feels anything. Since they don't feel pain it would be at most a "warm" feeling in the gut anyways, but you get that from drinking alcohol already.

The more interesting organ to consider igniting would be the lungs. Consumed alcohol is present in the lungs (thats why the police makes you blow to check you). And also we do have plenty of oxygen there. So if you set that on fire (if you reach an ignitable concentration) it would probably not extinguish immediatly but smolder on, consuming the oxygen. The person (unable to feel pain) would feel dizzy and sleepy due to CO2 poisoning which they could only stop by holding their breath. If they don't hold their breath and actually pass out they might die due to lack of oxygen.